# Populating request header values in making an HTTP request in netty

Tags: netty

[SOLVED]

I am unable to rectify the following error . Please help me in debugging the issue. I get the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method encode(Cookie..) from the type ClientCookieEncoder. ClientCookieEncoder was deprecated and the docs suggest earlier of a static modifier for encode method, which is absent in the newer version.

The code snippet has been referenced from http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.html

```
    package io.netty.example.http.snoop;

    ...
    import io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ClientCookieEncoder;
    import io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.DefaultCookie;
    ..

    public final class HttpSnoopClient {

    ...

    // Prepare the HTTP request.
            HttpRequest request = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(
                    HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, uri.getRawPath());
            request.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST, host);
            request.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.CLOSE);
            request.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCEPT_ENCODING, HttpHeaders.Values.GZIP);

     // Set some example cookies.
            request.headers().set(
                    HttpHeaders.Names.COOKIE,
                    ClientCookieEncoder.encode(
                            new DefaultCookie("my-cookie", "foo"),
                            new DefaultCookie("another-cookie", "bar")));
    ...

    }
```

Comment: are you sure you are using netty 4 ?

Comment: Currently I am using netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar in my libraries and http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.html documentation as a  reference.

Comment: I have found the error. The error was coming due to imports in eclipse. To avoid the deprecated methods i had used http.cookie.ClientCookieEncoder.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is :

```
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.ClientCookieEncoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultCookie;

….

// Set some example cookies.
        request.headers().set(
                HttpHeaders.Names.COOKIE,
                ClientCookieEncoder.encode(
                        new DefaultCookie("my-cookie", "foo"),
                        new DefaultCookie("another-cookie", "bar")));
```